# How do I delete specific row of records on gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

again.

On the gridview markup, I have these:

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dates">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="dates_label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("shipDates","{0:M/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate> 
   </asp:TemplateField>


   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>  
     <asp:HiddenField ID="ehide" Value='<%# Eval("eventId") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

The gridview displays several rows of records and using hidden form field, I am able to associate a row with its specific eventid from the events table.

Then below is the codebehind that attempts to delete each row of records.

```
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim dates_label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("dates_label"), Label)
        Dim shipDates = Date.ParseExact(dates_label.Value, "M/dd/yyyy", Nothing)

        Dim ehide = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ehide"), HiddenField)
        Dim eventid = ehide.Value

        Dim myConnectionString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
        Try
            myConnection.Open()
            strSQL = "Delete from tblEvents where username=@UserName and eventid = @eventid"
            com = New SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection)
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Session("username"))
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventid", eventid)
            Response.Write(strSQL)
            Response.End()
            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myConnection.Close()
            Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('Information Saved successfully')</SCRIPT>")
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx")
        Catch ex As SqlException
            Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</SCRIPT>")
        Finally
            myConnection.Close()
        End Try
    Next
```

When I run a debugger on this sub, it attempts to delete any row with the first eventid.

For instance, assume that there are 5 row of records on the event table and the eventIDs are 1,2,3,4,5. These are made up numbers for brevity.

If I try to delete the first record with eventId 1, I get:

delete from tblEvents where eventId = 1

If I try to delete the row with eventId 5, I still get:

Delete from tblEvents where eventId = 1

How do I resolve this in such that each row gets deleted by its rowId?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code of `ehide` inside `asp:TemplateField`, and remove `asp.net-mvc` tag because the question is not `mvc`.

Comment: @win, I am sorry the mvc was a mistake. I wanted to select asp.net. Thanks for correcting it.

Also, very sorry ehide, I posted the wrong code. I have posted the correct code now. BTW: eventid is integer if it helps. THANKS

Comment: why are you redirecting to a page in the middle of the loop?

Comment: also - `eventid` is a primary key and as such is typically stored in the GridView DataKeyNames collection.  Adding it as a Templated `HiddenField` is bad juju.

Comment: @Kenny Could you make sure that all data retrieve from database has different `eventId`? In other words, `eventId` are not 1 for all rows.

Comment: do you even get past the call to `Response.End()`?

Comment: That `For` loop is a code snippet that sits where in the CodeBehind?

Comment: No @fnostro, I usually comment that out before running my code.

Win, that's exactly what I need help on - how to ensure that when I click to delete, that a particular is deleted based on unique event ID. When I view source, I see different eventIds but not sure why I can delete based on ID of that particular row.

Comment: @fnostro, I don't understand your question.

Comment: that for loop, is it in the click event of the delete button? or some other event?

Comment: @fnostro, Oh I see - sorry. It is in the click event:

 `Sub cancelship_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions based on our discussion.

1. You have a gridview that has row selection enabled
2. You also have Delete Rows enabled. **`(EDIT: Just rememberd this option won't be available until you place the delete command in the SqlDataSource control)`**
3. That eventid is coming from a database

If this is all true then deleteing rows is ridiculously easy:

1. Place the eventid in GridView1 DataKeyNames via the Property page.
2. From the designer select the SqlDataSource control connected to GridView1
3. In the SqlDataSource Property List

   - a. find DeleteQuery and select it's (Query)
   - b. This will open the Command and Parameter Editor dialog box

     1. DELETE command: `"DELETE FROM tblEvents WHERE (username = @UserName) AND (eventid = @eventid)`
     2. click the `Refresh Parameters` button in the dialog
     3. Username: Parameter Source is Session, with SessionField as appropriate
     4. eventid: Parameter Source is Control, with ControlID of GridView1
4. Save it all

Now the Delete command is "wired" to your primary key (eventid) and delete should just work

Comment: thank very much for your efforts.

I still have the same issue though. When I click delete, I *don't* want to delete everything. 

I just want to delete the row that I clicked on.

That's why I gave the example of id 1,2,3,4,5 as an example.

If I click on row with Id 1, I want to delete just that row. If I click on another row with Id 2, I want just that row deleted.

I want to delete the specific row that I clicked

Again, I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: ok - does each row have it's own delete button? or do you select a row and then hit a delete button outside the gridview?

Comment: each row has its own delete button

Comment: ok - on more revision - i was answering while i was waiting for you to reply- give me a sec